# Python/Keras/Theano - Index out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy, theano, keras

I'm new to Keras and having some trouble with shapes, specially when it comes to RNNs and LSTMs.

**I'm running this code:**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=col,output_dim=70))
model.add(SimpleRNN(init='uniform',output_dim=30))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd")
model.fit(X=predictor_train, y=target_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=1,show_accuracy=True)
```

**I'm having this error:**

```
IndexError: index 143 is out of bounds for size 80
Apply node that caused the error: AdvancedSubtensor1(<TensorType(float32, matrix)>, Flatten{1}.0)
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(80, 70), (80,)]
Inputs strides: [(280, 4), (4,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

I don't understand where is that "index 143" coming from and how do I fix it.

Anyone available to enlight my journey?

Extra info below.

-- EDIT --
This "index 143" actually varies everytime I run the code. The numbers do not follow any apparent logic, the only thing I could notice is that, coincidentally or not, the smallest number that appeared was 80 (I ran the code more than 20 times)

---

**EXTRA INFO**

> **About predictor_train (X)**

type: 'numpy.ndarray'

shape: (119,80)

dtype: float64

> **About target_train (Y)**

type: class 'pandas.core.series.Series'

shape: (119,)

dtype: float64

```
Date
2004-10-01    0.003701
2005-05-01    0.001715
2005-06-01    0.002031
2005-07-01    0.002818
...
2015-05-01   -0.007597
2015-06-01   -0.007597
2015-07-01   -0.007597
2015-08-01   -0.007597
```

> **model.summary()**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initial input shape: (None, 80)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Layer (name)                  Output Shape                  Param #             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Embedding (Unnamed)           (None, None, 70)              5600                
SimpleRNN (Unnamed)           (None, 30)                    3030                
Dropout (Unnamed)             (None, 30)                    0                   
Dense (Unnamed)               (None, 1)                     31                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total params: 8661
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> **FULL TRACEBACK**

```
File "/Users/file.py", line 1523, in Pred
model.fit(X=predictor_train, y=target_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=1,show_accuracy=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 581, in fit
shuffle=shuffle, metrics=metrics)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 239, in _fit
outs = f(ins_batch)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 365, in __call__
return self.function(*inputs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 595, in __call__
outputs = self.fn()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 233, in __call__
link.raise_with_op(node, thunk)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 229, in __call__
thunk()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 768, in rval
r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/subtensor.py", line 1657, in perform
out[0] = x.take(i, axis=0, out=o)
IndexError: index 143 is out of bounds for size 80
Apply node that caused the error: AdvancedSubtensor1(<TensorType(float32, matrix)>, Flatten{1}.0)
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(80, 70), (80,)]
Inputs strides: [(280, 4), (4,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `X` variable probably contains the value 143. The `Embedding` layer will be of dimensions 80x70.

I'm assuming this is in the NLP field. This means you have a vocabulary size of 80 words each represented by vectors of length 70. Your `X` variable represents 119 sentences of length 80 (or 80 sentences of length 119) with its contents representing indices to your vocabulary. If it contains a word index greater than 80 this error will pop-up.

A more common value for your `col` variable is above 10.000. Of course, it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Not really, this number that appears there as 143 in this example varies every time I run the code again, so I understand it is not something related to dimensions of X but related to some other thing.

Comment: I didn't mean to say 143 has anything to do with the dimensions but it was inside your matrix `X`. If you are generating `X` randomly your code will fail with different values above 80 (the size of your vocabulary, which you passed to `Embedding` via `input_dim` --> `Embedding(input_dim=col,output_dim=70)`

Comment: You mean, inside my matrix X there is one "cell" with 143 as its value and it doesn't have any relation to shapes? (i'm not generating anything randomly col=len(predictor_train.columns) - it was a Pandas dataframe before and was turned into a numpy array to fit into Keras)

Comment: Yes. The values of `X` are indices to the rows of `Embedding`. col should be at least the maximum value of that dataframe +1.

I don't know what task you are working on. `Embedding`'s output is a matrix of shape  `(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 70)` in your case.

Comment: This is time series prediction based in 80 of input variables to predict the target

Comment: I see. I just saw your description of `X` again. The weird thing is you are using an `Embedding` layer when your inputs are floats. The input to `Embedding` should be integers: http://keras.io/layers/embeddings/

I don't think you fully understand how `Embedding` works, which I was trying to explain. Your inputs are converted to integers and then those integers are used as indices to the embedding matrix and retrieving a row. You only have 80 rows while your floats are above 80. This raises an `IndexError`.